# how to read & search excel data using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

i am using Apache POI for reading Excel rows and using as needed. In order to Enhance the script for better reusability, how can i search and find a String value in all sheets under Column A and read corresponding row. For Example in Sheet2 ColumnA i have Name called Peter and in ColumnB Date of birth of Peter is 12/18/1984. Can you give code sample to search Peter in ColumnA in Excel work book and return his Date of Birth from ColumnB? Below is the code i am using currently may not suit above criteria.

```
package com.Sample.GenericFunctionsLibrary;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;

public class TestUtil {
    public static Xls_Reader excel = null;

    public static String path = "./XLFile/Data.xlsx";

    public static String mailscreenshotpath;

    public static String generateTimeStamp() {

        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH); // 3
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR); // 2014
        int sec = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int date = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

        String timestamp = year + "_" + date + "_" + (month + 1) + "_" + day + "_" + min + "_" + sec;
        return timestamp;
    }

    public static boolean isExecutable(String tcid) {

        for (int rowNum = 2; rowNum <= excel.getRowCount("Credentials"); rowNum++) {

            if (excel.getCellData("Credentials", "TestCase_Name", rowNum).equals(tcid)) {
                if (excel.getCellData("Credentials", "runmode", rowNum).equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {

                    return true;

                } else {

                    return false;
                }

            }

        }

        return false;

    }

    public static Object[][] getData(String sheetName) {

        int rows = excel.getRowCount(sheetName);
        int cols = excel.getColumnCount(sheetName);

        Object[][] data = new Object[rows - 1][cols];

        for (int rowNum = 2; rowNum <= rows; rowNum++) { // 2

            for (int colNum = 0; colNum < cols; colNum++) {
                data[rowNum - 2][colNum] = excel.getCellData(sheetName, colNum, rowNum); // -2
            }
        }

        return data;

    }

    public static void zip(String filepath) {
        try {
            File inFolder = new File(filepath);
            File outFolder = new File("Reports.zip");
            ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFolder)));
            BufferedInputStream in = null;
            byte[] data = new byte[1000];
            String files[] = inFolder.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inFolder.getPath() + "/" + files[i]), 1000);
                out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i]));
                int count;
                while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1000)) != -1) {
                    out.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                out.closeEntry();
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------Read Data From
    // Excel------------------------------------
    public static String[][] GetValue(String Pathfile, String sheetName, int startrow) throws IOException {
        File excel = new File(Pathfile);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheet(sheetName);
        // System.out.println(startrow);
        int colNum = ws.getRow(startrow).getLastCellNum();
        // System.out.println(colNum);
        String[][] arrays = new String[1][colNum];
        for (int i = 0; i < colNum; i++) {
            XSSFRow row = ws.getRow(startrow);
            XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(i);
            arrays[0][i] = cellToString(cell);
            // System.out.println(arrays[0][i]);
        }
        return arrays;
    }

    // private static String cellToString(XSSFCell cell) {
    // Object result;
    // int type = cell.getCellType();
    //
    // switch(type)
    // {
    // case 0:
    // result = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    // break;
    // case 1:
    // result = cell.getStringCellValue();
    // break;
    // default:
    // throw new RuntimeException("there are no support for this type of cell");
    // }
    private static String cellToString(XSSFCell cell) {
        Object result;
        int type;
        try {
            type = cell.getCellType();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            type = 2;
        }

        switch (type) {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
            result = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            result = cell.getStringCellValue();
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
            result = "";
            break;
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("there are no support for this type of cell");
        }
        //
        return result.toString();

    }

}
```

Comment: So what is not working with your code?

Comment: This code shall not search for the keyword, infact i have to assign required values manually. I am checking if i can get some thing dynamic like my actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method will take a String value for the name to search and return the address for the first record found in the column next to it, assuming that the name is in the first column and the address is in the second column.  It will iterate over all sheets as asked.  It returns empty String if name is not found.  Try/catch block excluded for readability.

```
    public static String findAddressByName(String nameToSearch) {
        String fileLocation = "I:\\foo.xlsx";
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new File(fileLocation));
        for (int sheetIndex = 0; sheetIndex < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); sheetIndex++) {
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(sheetIndex);
            for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowIndex++) {
                XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
                if (row != null && row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue().equals(nameToSearch)) {
                    return row.getCell(1).getRawValue();
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: Great! If i have int value in the Second Column i am seeing "Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell" Error. All other String values working fine.

Comment: You can use getRawValue() instead of getStringCellValue().  Updated the answer to use that.

Comment: Glad I could help!  Please accept answer if issue is resolved.

Comment: Dan, If i have to Fetch the Text/val in the Third column what should i add to the code?